# Broken Delivery Estimate Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out how to code an app that allows you to select a mailing date with jquery datepicker, select Standard or First-class shipping from a dropdown, and calculate an estimated delivery date window (7-12 Days for Standard, 3-5 Days for First-class).

I had it working when the "Mailing in" [number] "Days" accepted a string input but then it broke when I added code for the datepicker.

I also need to keep weekends & holidays excluded from the shipping calculation.

Here's a link to the full pen: https://codepen.io/allyjfuller/pen/oNXvwJL

```js
$('#calculateShippingEstimate').click(function( event ) {
  
  //Prevent button from 'submitting' and reloading the page
  event.preventDefault();
  
  //Capture the mailing date
  var $mailingDate = $("#mailingDate").val();
  
  var $postageType = $("#postageType").val();
  var $shipStateShippingDuration = eval('data.shipTimes.' + $postageType);  
  var $totalShippingTime = parseInt($mailingDate) + parseInt($shipStateShippingDuration);
  
  //Create the date
  var date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth()+1;
  var day = date.getDate() + parseInt($totalShippingTime);
  var year = date.getFullYear();
```

```html
<form>
  <section>
    <label>Mailing on</label>
    <input id="mailingDate" placeholder="number"></input>
  </section>
  <section>
    <label>Postage:</label>
    <select id="postageType">
      <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
      <option value="FirstClass">First-Class</option>
    </select>
  </section>
  <input class="button" id="calculateShippingEstimate" type="submit" value="Get Estimated Delivery Date"></input>
  <div class="results"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking through your code snippet it seems like you're trying to hand roll a lot of features that already exist within the JS Date framework.

Once you get the starting date and the number of days for shipping, you can add those days together to create a final shipping date. From there and within a loop, you may go day by day and check whether the current date index is a weekday or not (using Date.getDay()).

With that you may check for Saturday [6] and Sunday [0] and then add days needed on top of the final date.

I've included my version of the code below with some console debugging but have not added code holidays. Holidays may be checked for using an array or map. Get all the holiday dates for a year and then have the current index check the holiday array/map to see if there are any matches. If there are, add another day to the final date.

The function for addDays is pulled from [here](https://codewithhugo.com/add-date-days-js/). It adds some explanation which I think you'll find helpful.

```
function addDays(date, days) {
 const copy = new Date(Number(date))
 copy.setDate(date.getDate() + days)
 return copy
}

// FINAL SHIPPING ESTIMATE

$('#calculateShippingEstimate').click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let mailingDateVal = $("#mailingDate").val();
  let shippingDuration = data.shipTimes[$("#postageType").val()];
  let mailingDate = new Date(mailingDateVal);

  console.log("final Date: " + addDays(mailingDate, shippingDuration));

  let finalDate = addDays(mailingDate, shippingDuration)

  let mailingDateIndex = new Date(mailingDate);
  while(mailingDateIndex <= finalDate) {
    console.log("current mailDateIndex: " + mailingDateIndex)

    if (mailingDateIndex === finalDate) {
     break;
    }

    // Weekend
    console.log(mailingDateIndex.getDay());
    if (mailingDateIndex.getDay() == 0 || mailingDateIndex.getDay() == 6) {
      console.log("weekend day hit! Adding day to final...")
      finalDate = addDays(finalDate, 1);
    }
    mailingDateIndex = addDays(mailingDateIndex, 1);
  }
});
```